# Linux 64 bit porting issue

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, porting

I am working on Linux 64 bit porting and we used a lots of long variable in our code. Now on Linux 64 long is 64 bit. We are facing problem in the bits manipulation code. 
I heard there are options LLP64(long as 32) and ILP64(long as 64).  But I don’t know the compiler option for it(g++). 
I have few more doubts, 
If I compile with option LLP64 then the executable will be native 64 bit or not?
With this option, can I include the 64 bit third libraries or not?

Answer (score 6):

gcc doesn't let you choose LLP64 , atleast not on linux targets. Even if it did, you wouldn't be ABI compatible with other libraries (including libc).

You'll have to either

- fix the code to deal with longs being 32 or 64 bit,
- change the code to use ints (or better int32_t).
- change the code to use long long (or better int64_t)
- compile the application as 32 bit (which will run fine on a 64 bit machine provided the 32 bit libraries it uses are present)

Comment: Worth to mention that the types int32_t and int64_t come from the  [stdint.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html). Many whyever do not know about it.